# How to add a ManyToManyField at runtime?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
def test_basic_addition(self):
    # create field
    f = models.ManyToManyField(to=X, related_name='bar')
    f.contribute_to_class(Y, 'x')

    # create table
    field = Y._meta.get_field_by_name('x')[0]
    through = field.rel.through

    fields = tuple((field.name, field) for field in through._meta.fields)

    db.create_table(through._meta.db_table, fields)
    db.create_unique(through._meta.db_table,
        ['%s_id' % name for name, f in fields
            if isinstance(f, models.ForeignKey)])


    x = X(name='foo')
    x.save()
    y = Y()
    y.save()
    y.x.add(x)

    print y.x.all()
```

The exception thrown is:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_basic_addition (test_app.tests.SimpleTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jpic/test_project/test_app/tests.py", line 41, in test_basic_addition
    print y.x.all()
  File "/home/jpic/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 116, in all
    return self.get_query_set()
  File "/home/jpic/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 543, in get_query_set
    return super(ManyRelatedManager, self).get_query_set().using(db)._next_is_sticky().filter(**self.core_filters)
  File "/home/jpic/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 621, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jpic/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 639, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/jpic/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1250, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "/home/jpic/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1122, in add_filter
    process_extras=process_extras)
  File "/home/jpic/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1316, in setup_joins
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'bar' into field. Choices are: id, name, users

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.017s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

`del X._meta._name_map` doesn't do the trick but i guess that's normal because it's a reverse field that come from the other model, Y.

Anyway, you can checkout my [test_project](https://github.com/jpic/test_project/) which isolates my problem, and then run `./manage.py test test_app` in your working copy to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to implement insane hacks to Django's AppCache, which apparently [is a pain](https://github.com/charettes/django-mutant/).

The cleanest solution is to use SQLAlchemy, here's an horrible proof of concept that after refactoring and some locking feature will become a python package:

```
import unittest

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from alembic.operations import Operations
from alembic.migration import MigrationContext

Base = declarative_base()
engine = sa.create_engine('mysql://root:root@localhost/jpic')
Session = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

conn = engine.connect()
ctx = MigrationContext.configure(conn)
op = Operations(ctx)

for table in ('person_car', 'cars', 'houses', 'persons'):
    op.drop_table(table)


class PersonTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_000_create_table(self):

        self.__class__.Person = type('Person', (Base,), {'__tablename__': 'persons',
            'id': sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)})

        self.__class__.Car = type('Car', (Base,), {'__tablename__': 'cars',
            'id': sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)})

        self.__class__.House = type('House', (Base,), {'__tablename__': 'houses',
            'id': sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)})

        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    def test_001_create_unicode_field(self):
        # create the column in the table - does not add it in the class
        field = sa.Column('unicode_field', sa.Unicode(50))
        op.add_column('persons', field)

        # create the column in the class - was not done above
        # a new instance to avoid conflicts
        field = sa.Column('unicode_field', sa.Unicode)
        self.__class__.Person.unicode_field = field

        subject = self.__class__.Person(unicode_field='hello unicode field')
        session.add(subject)

        subject = session.query(self.__class__.Person).first()
        self.assertEqual(subject.unicode_field, 'hello unicode field')

    def test_002_create_foreign_key(self):
        field = sa.Column('owner_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('persons.id'))
        op.add_column('houses', field)

        # create fk
        op.create_foreign_key('fk_house_owner', 'houses', 'persons', ['owner_id'], ['id'])

        field = sa.Column('owner_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('persons.id'))
        relation = orm.relationship('Person',
                backref=orm.backref('houses', lazy='dynamic'))
        self.__class__.House.owner_id = field
        self.__class__.House.owner = relation


        owner = session.query(self.__class__.Person).first()

        house = self.__class__.House()
        house.owner = owner
        session.add(house)

        house = session.query(self.__class__.House).first()

        self.assertEqual(house.owner, owner)
        # also test the reverse relation
        self.assertEqual(owner.houses.all(), [house])

    def test_003_create_many_to_many(self):
        association_table = sa.Table('person_car', Base.metadata,
            sa.Column('person_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('persons.id')),
            sa.Column('car_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('cars.id'))
        )

        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

        self.__class__.Person.cars = orm.relationship('Car',
                secondary=association_table,
                backref=orm.backref('persons', lazy='dynamic'))

        user1 = session.query(self.__class__.Person).first()
        user2 = self.__class__.Person()
        session.add(user2)

        car1 = self.__class__.Car()
        session.add(car1)
        car2 = self.__class__.Car()
        session.add(car2)

        user1.cars.append(car1)
        car2.persons.append(user1)
        session.commit()

        fresh_user1 = session.query(self.__class__.Person).get(user1.id)
        self.assertEqual(len(fresh_user1.cars), 2)
        self.assertTrue(car1 in fresh_user1.cars)
        self.assertTrue(car2 in fresh_user1.cars)

        fresh_car1 = session.query(self.__class__.Car).get(car1.id)
        self.assertEqual(fresh_car1.persons.all(), [user1])
```

Note that this works on mysql, but not sqlite nor postgres.

Hello Flask and SQLAlchemy B)